# How to go back to previous page in Next.js using `next/router`?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm using Next.js for my application and I'm facing some issues on routing to the previous route of the application. I'm aware of the router function `back()` which is similar to `window.history.back()`, I would like to go back to the route when a `Link` is clicked, and if the previous link isn't from my application or is `null`, I would like to go to the home page as a default.

I used libraries like `react-router-last-location` for my react app, but I wanna see if there are better ways to do it in Next.js via `next/router`.

Here is my sample code:

```tsx
<div className={styles['icon-container']}>
  <Link  href="/"><a>
      <img src="icon.svg"></img>
  </a></Link>
</div>
```

if i use router.back() in the href input, the page goes back automatically even before it loads, how do i solve this issue?

Comment: Could you add some more information about the use case, i.e. why you want to do this. This will help people give more rounded answers. :)

Comment: I don't understand your use case and/or requirements, but I think hijacking the back navigation to keep users in your app is a rather poor UX. I'd like to think I'm not alone in thinking if I accidentally navigated into your webapp and immediately try to back out and continually bounce to your homepage that I'll never want to visit again.

Comment: No i'm not hijacking the back navigation! This is a custom back button which will be present in my site so that they can view a post and go back to the feed!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<Link>` can't go outside of your app. (but `router.back()` can)

You can't use `router.back()` directly in the code, you need to do something like :

```
<img onClick={router.back} src="icon.svg" />
```

`<Link>` does not have onClick property.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={router.back}>
      Click here to go back
    </button>
  )
}
```

Source of info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Comment: How does this code prevent back navigation out of the app and redirect to home page instead?

Comment: Don't really know, with Router you can't do this. You need to check .sessionStorage or .localstorage

Comment: @DrewReese You can use solution outlined here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36723

Comment: @justdvl Perhaps your comment would be better directed to ChiTest since this is their answer that doesn't appear to explain how to prevent navigation out of the app. I'm actually surprised this answer is accepted and got 8 upvotes for some reason. Perhaps the question really was just about effecting a regular vanilla back navigation.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerback

Answer (score 0):

The solution offered here does not work for newer versions of next.js. There have been several changes (see the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating)):

- You have to use the App Router's `useRouter` from `next/navigation`
- You have to specify that this code is executed on the client side with `'use client';`

The easiest way is to create a component `BackButton.tsx` similar to the following:

```
'use client';
import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation';

export default function BackButton() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <button onClick={router.back}>back</button>
  )
}
```

and then inside your page import the `BackButton` as shown by this example:

```
import BackButton from "@/components/BackButton";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col p-12">
      <h1>[<BackButton/>] Title</h1>
      // ... whatever else you have ...
    </main>
  );
}
```